# Value inside array having same object id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

Recently I was playing with arrays and found out a weird behavior. I created a new array using Array.new.

`arr = Array.new(4,"happy")`

`["happy", "happy", "happy", "happy"]`

I appended a word into the second element in that array like shown below

`arr[1] <<" Dino"`

When I looked at arr, I was expecting an array with the second element having an appended word. But to my surprise array returned with all elements with the appended word.

`["happy Dino", "happy Dino", "happy Dino", "happy Dino"]`

How can this happen? Are we creating copies of the same string when we are creating the array? It doesn't happen if we use `arr[1]= " Dino"`. Somebody can explain why this is happening?

Comment: I'm not seeing this behavior, `ar = ["happy", "happy", "happy", "happy"]
ar[1] <<" Dino"`, the output is 
`happy
happy Dino
happy
happy`

Comment: @Bman70 it won't happen when you do like that. Try using Array.new(size, string). When we declare and initialize an array with new. I am thinking the same string is getting copied to all elements, Which makes their object id same.

Comment: By gum, you're right. Strange.

Comment: Can you explain what *precisely* is unclear to you about the documentation of `Array::new`? That way, the Ruby developers can improve the documentation so that future developers don't fall into the same trap as you did. Please, help making the world a better place!

Comment: The documentation contains a [common gotchas](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-c-new-label-Common+gotchas) section explaining what's going on: _"the same object will be used as the value for all the array elements […] changes to one of them will affect them all"_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you a right. See the [ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-c-new)

> When a size and an optional default are sent, an array is created with size copies of default. Take notice that all elements will reference the same object default.

You can initialize array in a way like this:

```
arr = Array.new(4){ 'happy' }
```

Answer (score 2):

When we take Array.new(4, "Happy") it will create 4 elements with same object id. We can observe in irb `arr[1].object_id => 2880099` , `arr[2].object_id => 2880099` and remaining 2 elements also will return same object id.

So when we try like `arr[1] << "Something"` , this string will append to all the same object id's.

Now if we take another element for **arr** like `arr.push("newString")`. Now if see the last element object id `arr.last.object_id => 4889988`,it's different now.

So if we try same command `arr[1] << "Something"` it won't be effect to newly inserted element because object id is different.

if you don't want this behaviour the use `Array.new(4){ 'String' }`